# Соединение (Connect) с базой данных (java JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, dao

Пишу приложение на Java с использованием JDBC для базы данных по шаблону DAO. Сколько раз нужно создавать соединение с базой данных? То есть если я делаю запрос, то надо:

> СОЕДИНИТСЯ С БД -> СДЕЛАТЬ ЗАПРОС -> ЗАКРЫТЬ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ С БД и так для каждого запроса?

или

> СОЕДИНИТСЯ С БД -> СДЕЛАТЬ ЗАПРОС .... СДЕЛАТЬ ЗАПРОС (на протяжении работы приложения) -> ЗАКРЫТЬ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ С БД (завершить работу с приложением)

Comment: Нет, не нужно поднимать новое соединение на каждый запрос.

Comment: На счет шаблона не знаю, но чисто с технической стороны по одному подключению вы можете сделать несколько запросов. Подключаться каждый раз к БД будет медленно, идеальный вариант использовать пул подключений к БД.

Comment: Вас понял, благодарю за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем меньше соединений наружу (вне JVM) тем лучше. Если у вас не дико навороченное кровавое Enterprise приложение, то достаточно одного соединения.

Простой вариант - вы можете сделать в DAO классе метод аля `getConnection()`
и объявить приватное поле класса типа `Connection`,

например вот так:

```
class YourDao {

    private Connection cnn;

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection result;

        if (cnn != null) {
            result = cnn;
        } else {
            result = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

а потом воткнуть его в те методы где требуется соединение. везде где требуется проверка соединения будет либо создаваться коннект (если его не было), либо использоваться уже существующее соединение